# Finding the correlation of every row and column between 2 matrices in R, then taking the max and min values

Tags: r, correlation, matrix, extreme-value

I'm using R, and I need to find the correlation between every row and column of matrix A and B (ex: the correlation between the 1st row of matrix A and 1st column of matrix B, 2nd row of matrix A and 1st column of matrix B, 2nd row of matrix A and 2nd column of matrix B, etc.)

I realized I can do this by doing

cor(matrixA[1,],matrixB)

cor(matrixA[1,],matrixB)

cor(matrixA[1,],matrixB)

... until I get to the very last row of matrixA (matrixA has 17000 rows)

My question is, how do I do this faster without having to type in each command?
In addition, the most important part, is how do I get the max and min correlation values of ALL the correlation values I will have calculated in this way?

Many thanks!
T

Comment: just 'normalize' each row of `A` and column of `B`; (subtract sample mean, divide by sample standard deviation) then take the matrix product of the normalized matrices. done.

Comment: duh, I didn't read the fine manual. Just do `corrs <- cor(t(A),B)`. Look at the help for `cor`.

Answer (score 4):

`cor` does this for you:

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000*20),nrow=1000)
B <- matrix(rnorm(20*400),nrow=20)
ABcor <- cor(t(A),B)
max(ABcor)
```

Comment: how do you know what row and column of the 2 matrices produced this max correlation value?

Comment: try `arrayInd(which.max(ABcor),.dim=dim(ABcor))` and `? which.max` and `? arrayInd`.